# Knockout showing data from selection

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using knockout to create a selection list. Each selection item is a object with a couple of variables in it. When an item is selected I want do display another variable from the selected object in a `span`.

The selection works but no data is displayed in the span containing the `data1:` text.

Any ideas?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/e24zoyp6/

The code: 
JS

```
var _ViewModel = {};

$(document).ready(function () {
    setupView();
});

function setupView() {
    var Month = function (longName, shortName, value) {
        this.ShortName = shortName;
        this.MonthName = longName;
        this.MonthNumber = value;
    };

    _ViewModel = {
        // These are the initial options
        monthSelection: ko.observableArray([
            new Month("January", "Jan", 1),
            new Month("February", "Feb", 2),
            new Month("March", "Mar", 3)
        ]),
        SelectedMonth: ko.observable()
    };

    ko.applyBindings(_ViewModel);
}
```

Html

```
<select data-bind="
    options: monthSelection, 
    optionsText: 'MonthName',
    optionsValue: 'MonthNumber',
    value: SelectedMonth,
    optionsCaption: 'Which Month?'">            
</select> 

<div data-bind="visible: SelectedMonth"> data1: 
    <span data-bind="text: SelectedMonth() ? SelectedMonth().ShortName : 'unknown'"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using the `MonthNumber` as your `optionsValue`. This means your `SelectedMonth` will only contain the number of the month and not the whole `Month` object that is why your `text` binding is not working.

To fix it just remove the `optionsValue: 'MonthNumber',` and KO will use the whole object when you change the selection:

```
<select data-bind="
    options: monthSelection, 
    optionsText: 'MonthName',
    value: SelectedMonth,
    optionsCaption: 'Which Month?'">            
</select>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5w082hw/).

Comment: ah, thank you. Just starting out with KO. Not used to all the "Magic" its doing yet.

Comment: Also gets confused when you look at the html code its adding `value="" ` to the `option` when you dont specify `value`.